# Why is this Promise object's status 'fulfilled'?

Tags: javascript

If asynchronous functions execute after the main thread, then why does `k`, printed to the console, have `[[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled".` Surely a promise can only be `fulfilled` when it's successfully completed its asynchronous behaviour. Shouldn't it be 'pending' or something? It does say pending somewhere if you look at the picture.

```js
function fetchDog(){
  k = fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random") 
  console.log(k);
};

fetchDog();
```

[image]

Comment: Hover over the blue “i”.

Comment: in the debugger - it might be evaluated later.

Comment: It initially shows pending but by the time you expand it, it's already fulfilled.

Comment: Objects in console are not snapshots, they are live objects that reflect modifications after you log them

Comment: @charlietfl This exactly - was having a hard time wording it.

Comment: So after logging to the console the promise object, it then resolves and updates. That's why we can see a `[[PromiseValue]]` too. Think I got it, thanks

Comment: Simple example is `let o ={}; console.log(o); o.foo='bar';` then expand that object